# Fixing the value of template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Is the following permissible when using templates.

```
template <typename PAR1 = X,
          typename PAR2 = Y,
          typename PAR3 = Z>
class Base {
   //some stuff inside
};

template <typename PAR1
          typename PAR2 = Z>
class Derived : public Base <PAR1,Y,PAR2> {
   //some stuff here
};
```

what i want here is that Derived class should always have the PAR2 type as Y.

Can we fix the parameter value when others parameters after it as optional while inheriting ?

Comment: The answer, in any case, is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are confused by template default value and partial specialization. Because Base takes 3 parameters with default value, you could instantiate Base with from 0 to 3 parameters.

```
Base<> b1;              #1, PAR1=X,   PAR2=Y,   PAR3=Z
Base<int> b2;           #2  Par1=int, PAR2=Y,   PAR3=Z
Base<int, int> b3;      #3  PAR1=int, PAR2=int, PAR3=Z
Base<int, int, int> b4; #4  PAR1=int, PAR2=int, PAR3=int
```

In Derived class, you are inheriting from situation `#4` which is of course valid.

So you can inherit from any form of Base above.

Base template parameter can be independent type(value) or passed from `template <typename PAR1, typename PAR2 = Y>`

```
template <typename PAR1,
          typename PAR2 = Y>
class Derived : public Base <> {
};
```

OR

```
template <typename PAR1,
          typename PAR2 = Y>
class Derived : public Base <PAR1> {
};
```

OR

```
template <typename PAR1,
          typename PAR2 = Y>
class Derived : public Base <PAR1, PAR2> {
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you wanted something like this. So, it is possible

```
class X{};
class Y{};
class Z{};

template <typename PAR1 = X,
          typename PAR2 = Y,
          typename PAR3 = Z>
class Base {
   //some stuff inside
};

template <typename PAR1, typename PAR3>
class Derived : public Base <PAR1,Y,PAR3> {
};

int main()
{
    Derived<X, Z> d;
}
```

EDIT 2:
Though unrelated to the OP, it is good to know that in partial specialization, the partial specialized class template parameters have the default value of the primary template

```
class X{};
class Y{};
class Z{};

template <typename PAR1 = X, typename PAR2 = Y, typename PAR3 = Z>
class Base {
public:
    void f() {
        std::cout << typeid(PAR1).name() << " " << typeid(PAR2).name() << " " << typeid(PAR3).name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << 1;
    }
};

template<typename PAR2, typename PAR3> class Base<X, PAR2, PAR3>
{
public:
    void f() {
        // PAR2 is by default Y and PAR3 is by default Z
        std::cout << typeid(PAR2).name() << " " << typeid(PAR3).name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << 2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base<X> b;   // instantiation of partially specialized template
    b.f();
}
```

Comment: actually, yes something like that only.

Comment: wasn't sure, as OP says PAR2=Z, instead of PAR3=Z